# Add new state option for task in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs

How can I add new state value for task item in web TFS 2012.
I use agile template.

Comment: Are you using tfs.visualstudio.com (TF Service) or an on-premise TFS instance (TF Server)?

Comment: tfs.visualstudio.com (TF Service)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can't for the TFS Service but in general for how to do that, you can use GUI by installing Team Foundation Power Tool and start using Process Customization Tool, you will open the Work Item that you want to customize and drag and drop new state, see the following image:

[image]

For more information you can see detailed video on how to do that here:
http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/customize-tfs-process-2010-video/

Comment: The original question was about TFS 2012. Radwan could you please update the link. For now, here is the TFS 2012 version. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudiouk/archive/2013/01/19/adding-additional-states-onto-the-agile-task-board-in-tfs2012.aspx

Comment: I followed your link but the .wit file is opened as a plain .xml file, I can't see the flow chart style of image. Am I missing some component?

Comment: You need to install TFS PowerTool

Comment: Looked everywhere, but in the toolbox!

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, you cannot modify the process templates on Team Foundation Service at the moment.

There's quite a few restrictions that you can compare [here](http://lajak.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/tfs-2012-versions-of-team-foundation-server/).

Answer (score 0):

The main process is described here:

[How to customize TFS 2010 work items](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/1/how-to-customize-tfs-2010-work-items-and-workflows/)

But, yes. For now you can not modify the process templates on Team Foundation Service